# iPhone UIWebview -- Saving an image already downloaded

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have an iPhone app with an embedded UIWebview (Safari) control.  I'd like to be able to store the images from certain webpages locally.

Can I programmatically access the path where UIWebview downloads images?  Or do I need to parse the HTML and then go find the image resource out on the net and download it again?

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if you can access the preloaded images from Safari's cache...

However you can easily find the image URLs without parsing HTML, by running a bit of javascript instead:

```
NSString *script = @"var n = document.images.length; var names = [];"
                    "for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {"
                    "     names.push(document.images[i].src);"
                    "} String(names);";
NSString *urls = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
// urls contains a comma-separated list of the image URLs.
```

Comment: And you just need to add 
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.url.com/image.jpeg"]];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, self, nil, nil); to save the image to Photos album.

Comment: This is not a solution the author asking for. He doesn't want to request for images on the internet as they are loaded in webview already. I've voted up the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can save the images using the UIWebview directly, you'r going to have to fetch the images manually...

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I have not tried this.

If you can find out their names, UIImage responds to +(UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*) which the docs imply might get the image back from a device wide cache.

I'd be interested in knowing the results of any experiments.